# CSS center in IE6, 7, and 8

Tags: css

This code works for IE7 and 8 but not for 6. How can I get it to work for 6. Or is there a better way to do it?

```
#contentLoading {
width:90px;
height: 90px;
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
background:url(_img/ajax-loader4.gif) no-repeat center #fff;
text-align:center;
padding:10px;
font:normal 16px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
border:2px solid #666;
margin-left: -50px;
margin-top: -50px;
z-index:2;
overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: For IE6 & position: fixed;, this (valid, future-proof) hack will often suffice: position: fixed !important; position: absolute; (the order matters).

Answer (score 6):

Did you know that IE6 does not support `position: fixed;`? It will be rendered as a `static` element.

Comment: Switching it to "position: absolute" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use something like:

```
#contentLoading {
  width: 90px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to center the #contentLoading div within a container you can do it like so:

```
#contentLoading {
   width: 500px; /* whatever width you want */
   margin: 0px auto; /* top and bottom margin of zero, left and right are automatically calculated based on the space available in the enclosing container */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Ie6, you need to text-align:center the body in your CSS, and then style the main wrapping div with text-align:left, to re-align the text toe the left.

Here is a example.

```
body{
    text-align: center; /*This alligns all content to the center for IE6*/
}

#mainWrapper{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: left; /*This re aligns all content within this id to the left*/
}
```